# express is not defined...?? even after its installation

Tags: node.js, express

my code under package.json

```
{
  "name": "mernstack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "social network for developers",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "sonali",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.6",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^10.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

i am getting this error even it was working very well earlier...?? after getting this error i have reinstall express at that timeit was showing byte error after getting that error i have uninstall npm and reinstalled it and after that i am getting this error please help me

Comment: show your code where you initialize express

Comment: As everyone else here is pointing out `Cannot find module 'express'` would mean express is not installed.  But you have `express is not defined`, which means you are not initializing the variable `express` properly.

Comment: but i have intialized it...then suddenly i am getting the error identifier 'express'is already declared

Comment: Questions about code MUST include the relevant code pasted into your question and formatted appropriately as code.  I don't know how you expect us to solve a problem with your code when you don't show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we can see your code, but did you initialise express properly?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Comment: yes i have now i am getting the syntax error Identifier 'express' has already been declared

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate express in your application

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Or if you're using the new imports

```
import express from 'express';
```

Comment: const express = require('express'); i have this code written in server.js file

Comment: Identifier 'express' has already been declared at new script (vm.js:74:7) at createscript (vm.js:246:10) at Object.runInThisContext(vm.js:298:10) at module._compile(internal/module/cjs/loader.js:713:10) thisis my error

Comment: use require OR import. Not both. Or if you have multiple `const express` would give the same error. You can only declare a variable once.

Comment: const express = require("express"); i have written this line in my first server.js file and have used const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router(); in my users.js file

Comment: i have declared variable only once in a file ...in which ever file it is needed i have declared only once

Comment: Try instantiating express only once in your application and export the instantiated object from the file so you can use that instance in other files in your application